# How to share static variable across components in Angular

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a parent component **Component A** which has 3 child components inside it, say
**1.UserInfo
2.BranchInfo
3.MiscInfo"**

These 3 components will be linked to parent component "Component A" via the breadcrumb menu. I need to save the **UserInfo** form values, **BranchInfo** form values and make it availiable at the **MiscInfo** component from which I can store all these at one shot into DB.

I tried creating a **Service** and storing these values in a **static** variable. But it did not work as new instantiation of service was made for each component.

How can I solve my issue?

Comment: You can achieve that using a service to have access to static variables. I don't know why doesn't work in your case. Please, create a minimal reproducible example in Stackblitz.

Comment: Provide the service in the right module and just do the DI inside the constructor, don't inject the service in the `component's decorator`.

Comment: Also remember to post some code (minimal amount to reproduce your issue) when adding a question :)

Comment: What about using Subject rxjs to emit any changes between the components and store always the current value of your data that you want to share

Comment: @RebaiAhmed Thanks this actually helped. I will share this approach as acceptable answer soon.